# Testing for equality using floor function in R does not work

Tags: estimation, bias, quantiles

I am doing research on quantiles and I have following problem.

The sample size and the quantile levels are specified as follows.

```
n <- 200
probs <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)
```

The product of n and probs returns integers.

```
np <- (n * probs)
```

Thus, the floor function of the product should return the same integers.

```
floor_np <- floor((n * probs))
```

However, not all values are TRUE.

```
np == floor_np
```

To give two examples:

```
x1 <- np[6]
x1
[1] 12
y1 <- floor_np[6]
y1 
[1] 12
x1 == y1
[1] FALSE

x2 <- np[7]
x2
[1] 14
y2 <- floor_np[7]
y2
[1] 13
x2 == y2
[1] FALSE
```

Does anybody has an idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: You know from decimal arithmetic that your expression implies integer results, but R like any similar program uses binary arithmetic underneath what you see. Only of a few of 0.01(0.01)0.99 have exact binary equivalents, so very occasionally what should be true isn't quite true.

Comment: `np` is not declared as integer, hence the discrepancy, see eg that `range(as.integer(np)-floor(np))` returns 0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `probs` are `numeric` type. Just coerce them to integers and this works as expected.

```
> class(np)
[1] "numeric"

> class(as.integer(np))
[1] "integer"

as.integer(np)[6] == 12
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works indeed. However, I think that the problem exists within the quantile function of the package stats.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please consider up-voting and/or accepting it.